# How to know heights of elements before they get rendered in react?

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-virtualized

I have a long list of elements in UI it leads to performance issue. I am facing issues after integrating 'react-virtualization'. The screen is blinking while scrolling up/down. Can suggest, how do make it work with elements of different heights?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add some code that you have tried

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check [ask] for more info.

Comment: Also check out the `react-virtualized` docs, specifically the ones about `CellMeasurer`. There are examples of its use in the repo and on the demo site.